# Is it okay to use common abbreviations as variable names in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, would it be okay to use "pd" instead of "pandas" and "df" instead of "data_frame" in Python code?

On the one hand, using short variable names (less than 3 characters in length) is generally bad practice, stylistically, and from a maintainability perspective.

On the other hand, df and pd are rather ubiquitous for any Python programmer that uses the Pandas library.

What say you?

Comment: This is quite opinion based but the community has pretty much widely adopted `pd`, `np`, `df`, etc...

Comment: Short variable names are not bad practice if there is a convention surrounding their use. Does anyone get confused by `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`?

Comment: To the extent that there exist agreed-on conventions in the Python community, they're documented at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions. Anything outside PEP-8 is, generally speaking, subjective / not subject to universal agreement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow really isn't the place for questions like this, may I suggest the [Programmers Stack Exchange?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

But since it is here, speaking as someone who has been forced to work with a massive C codebase with lots of 1-3 letter variable names and no documentation for the last few months, more verbose and descriptive variable names are probably better, especially if other people have to work with your code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better practice to use more letters, because if other people review your code, the variable `pd` would not make sense to them.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless it's longer than 7 or 8 characters, as a rule of thumb. Get a proper IDE that can do some decent autocomplete, like PyCharm (autocomplete dialog automatically pops up and enter completes the variable).

`df` is too cryptic. Take a look at C++, with all its cryptic names `itoa`, `itoa`, `stoi`, etc.

PyCharm can do variable/class/function renaming automatically too.